# How to enable simultaneous output to multiple audio devices?

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I am attempting to configure simultaneous audio output to two or more connected devices on Arch Linux with KDE.

I have tried installing paprefs. This did not work as the audio device that is supposed to mirror to all connected audio devices did not show up in system sound panel.

I have also tried to follow [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379376/how-to-achieve-automated-simultaneous-outputs-with-pipewire/1382215#1382215) and use `pacmd` `module-combine-sink` to create a combined sink of the speaker and the headphone. The sink is created but I am unable to set it as default. It does not show up in the system audio panel, and any attempt to set it as default did not work.

If I run the sink creation command in `pactl`, I get `Failure: Input/Output Error`.

I have tried with analog or digital headphones, neither have worked.

What have I been doing wrong? Is there an easier software alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `pactl load-module module-combine-sink` worked for me. See the attached screenshot - audio is playing to all output devices.

> It does not show up in the system audio panel, and any attempt to set it as default did not work.

It's a **virtual** device, make sure those are visible:

[image: Combined Virtual Output Device for PulseAudio/PipeWire]

If you boggled your PipeWire configuration you could restart it this way:

`systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.socket pipewire-pulse.service pipewire.service wireplumber.service` or simply reboot.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I think the reason why my previous ```pactl``` command did not work is because I was using the device name returned by ```pacmd```. The names returned by these two are apparently different for my USB audio adapter.

Comment: Running the ```systemctl``` says that the ```.service``` files are not found, so I installed pipewire-pulse to replace pulseaudio package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simultanously output on exactly two devices, you can do the following:

1. Use `pavucontrol` or similar tool to set the default audio output to your device #1.
2. Run
   `arecord --buffer-time=1 - | aplay --buffer-time=1 -` to create a process that will replay whatever is on its audio input to an audio output.
3. Use `pavucontrol` or similar tool to set the input of this process to a "Monitor of device #1"
4. Set the output of this process to device #2.

The minus of this solution is that you might sometimes get worse audio quality on device #2.