# How to output to multiple audio devices at once?

Tags: linux, gnome, audio, pulseaudio, output

I have multiple audio output devices connected to my desktop including headphones, earphones and speakers. When I use Gnome's GUI to select a new output device the previously selected device stops outputting sound and only the newly selected device outputs sound. How can I make it so that my linux system outputs sound to two or more devices simultaneously? Audio server is `pulseaudio`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable simultaneous output to multiple audio devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729298/how-to-enable-simultaneous-output-to-multiple-audio-devices)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simultanously output on exactly two devices, you can do the following:

1. Use `pavucontrol` or similar tool to set the default audio output to your device #1.
2. Run `arecord --buffer-time=1 - | aplay --buffer-time=1 -` to create a process that will replay whatever is on its audio input to an audio output.
3. Use `pavucontrol` or similar tool to set the input of this process to a "Monitor of device #1"
4. Set the output of this process to device #2.

The minus of this solution is that you might sometimes get worse audio quality on device #2.